# how do you make the product attributes on view pages into drop downs

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product

i am using `magento 2.2`. i want to make my `configurable product attributes`, like `Product size`, `into dropdowns`.

how do i do that. i noticed its possible from this picture on another forum

[image]

Comment: Check this link for creating configurable products https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-create-configurable-product-magento-2.html